# In a Rails app, how can I use a button to run a non-restful controller method? Getting no routes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my application I have a link_to helper method:

```
<%= link_to "Downgrade", :controller => :subscriptions, :action => :downgrade, class: "btn btn-primary", remote: true %>
```

In my controller I have this code:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js

  def downgrade
    # some code
  end
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"downgrade", :class=>"btn btn-primary", :controller=>"devise/subscriptions"}
```

Here is my routes.rb code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :wikis
 devise_for :users
 resources :users, only: [:update]
 root to: 'welcome#index'
 resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

I know Rails is expecting a route for this but I don't know what route I would use since the method isn't a restful verb.  Maybe there is another way without using the `link_to` which allows me to directly call a controller method from a view?  Maybe I need to restructure where things are as well. Any help is appreciated.

Let me know if there is more code you would need to fully assess this situation.

Comment: Jo dude, if my answer helped you, check my answer below ;) it definitely helps out. Also, you can remove your comments since they are superfluous noise.

Answer (score 1):

### Basic setup

first you need to setup your route in **routes.rb**

```
get 'downgrade' => 'subscriptions#downgrade', :as => :downgrade_subscription
```

This will redirect `/downgrade` to your *subscriptions* controller & *downgrade* action. The `as` option saves this route into a variable you can call from all your **views**.

```
<%= link_to "Downgrade", downgrade_subscriptions_path, class: "btn btn-primary", remote: true %>
```

### Further configuration

You can also nest this route inside your `subscription resources` like so:

```
resources :subscriptions do
  get 'downgrade' => 'subscriptions#downgrade', :as => :downgrade_subscription
end
```

This will create the path `/subscriptions/downgrade` instead of `/downgrade`.

The [Rails Docs on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) does a great job explaining this in more detail. Definitely check it out!

Comment: Besides this, I think it will be better to specify respond_to :js inside the downgrade method.

Comment: Adding the code to the route generates a "Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes" error message.  The link_to is in a view partial which is called from a devise registration edit page.  So I think that makes this more complicated.  You can see the error from my post that Rails is trying to use devise/subscription.

Comment: sorry I made a typo. Could you try again?

Comment: You can use your routes from anywhere in your project, so that won't be a problem

Comment: That worked.  I would up vote the answer since it solved my problem but I don't have 15 reputation points.  Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Now you do ;) by the way, you can always accept an answer by selecting the checkmark under the votes. This shows that the answer worked for you & gives rep to the author too

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this on your **routes.rb**

```
match '/downgrade_subscription', :to => 'subscriptioni#downgrade', :via => :get
```

Comment: `match` is deprecated since Rails 4. Use the specific method instead